# How to price odd job

Tags: pay-rate

The job is thus:

- Take email from random address generator
- Verify the address as a valid residential address
- If it is not residential or it is not a valid address, it doesn't count
- Gather several thousand addresses, with a maximum of 10,000, making sure that the higher populated the area is, the more addresses I have for it
- And once I have my addresses, upload them all to an Excel sheet

It's part information gathering, part information verification, then sorting to make sure I have higher numbers in certain areas in accordance to its population, and then data entry with either basic typing of it all, or a short Excel macro to store it all.

I haven't the foggiest clue how much to charge for this. How would I work this out?

Comment: I don't understand what answer you are expecting here. As with all pricing for *any* project... calculate the amount of time you think it will take to complete, then multiply that by your hourly rate.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like insanely difficulty but it will take your time to do it correctly.

To price it, break the job into smaller pieces like implementing a random generator. Be honest to yourself, ask yourself how many hours would that take you to do it.

For example, implementing a random generator should not take you long, but collecting addresses will take longer unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Now multiply your hour rate with the number of hours you think you might need.

Answer (score 1):

it's always tricky to estimate jobs that you haven't done before!

When there is so much uncertainty, there is a simple recipe. Break down the task into repeatable jobs and bring it down to a level that you can control. Quote the first one at fixed price, then re-quote for the rest.

For example:

Do a single email address or single geographical area first, so that you can understand the work required. You quote this at fixed, reasonable cost and take the hit if you make a mistake. Then quote for the rest of the job after you've done that work. Make sure that the client knows the price can go up or down after that first unit.

[as an additional benefit you also have the chance to walk away from the project if it turns out to be a nightmare]

You sell this approach to the client quite easily: It's transparent and fair. Be honest, you haven't done that kind of work before and want to make sure they get a fair deal. You don't want to price it too high (they will lose) or too low (making it unsustainable for you - again they lose due to quality of work).

Hope that helps, happy to answer any questions!